# Does C# JIT compiler optimize null-check?

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, jit, null-check

There are many articles online that list the optimizations made by the C# JIT before executing a piece of code. For example [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973852.aspx) on MSDN talks about:

> Constant folding, Constant and copy propagation, Common subexpression
>   elimination, Code motion of loop invariants, Dead store and dead code
>   elimination, Register allocation, Method inlining, Loop unrolling
>   (small loops with small bodies).

My question is: does the JIT compiler deals also with useless null-checks? I can't find any source treating this question.

In the same article I read:

> since the C# language specification ensures that any call on a null
>   object reference throws a NullReferenceException, every call site must
>   ensure the instance is not null. This is done by dereferencing the
>   instance reference; if it is null it will generate a fault that is
>   turned into this exception.

So, suppose I write a piece of code like this:

```
if (person != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
}
```

The `person.Name` calls again a second null-check that is cleary useless, and the compiler could remove it. Or not?

I read that in Java this is already done (some sources between many [here](http://jpbempel.blogspot.it/2013/09/null-check-elimination.html), [here](http://prolangs.cs.vt.edu/refs/docs/kawahito-asplos00.pdf) and [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.91.4165&rep=rep1&type=pdf)).

If C# does it too, do you know some source or documentation that talks about that?

If instead C# doesn't do it, do you know why? Is there an intrinsic difficulty in implementing such a feature for a .NET environment that the Java JIT does not encounter?

Comment: Only as a side-effect of the normal optimizations, like dead-code elimination.  Which ought to be quite rare.  In general the jitter optimizer has no special knowledge of code performing a null-pointer check and treats pointers as volatile.  Pretty essential in any VM with a garbage collector that arbitrarily modifies pointers when it compacts the heap.  Notable is that the C# compiler itself can eliminate the check, it does so when you use the elvis operator (`?.`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Null` check optimization done by the compiler (Roslyn, not Jitter) [in several cases](https://mycodingplace.wordpress.com/2014/04/22/call-vs-callvirt-instruction/), when its completly save to do that.

For example when you use `?` (Elvis operator).

```
IL_0006: stloc.0              // Pop a value from stack into local variable 0
IL_0007: ldloc.0              // Load local variable 0 onto stack
IL_0008: brtrue.s IL_000c     // Branch to target if value is non-zero (true), short form
IL_000a: br.s IL_0013         // Branch to target, short form
IL_000c: ldloc.0              // Load local variable 0 onto stack
IL_000d: call instance void Foo::Bar() // Call method indicated on the stack with arguments
```

Another example is code like this:

```
new Bar().Foo();
```

The compiler generates for this `call` instruction and not `callvirt` (which means, no null check on `this`)

In other cases, you can't be sure that `this` not going to be null.

Anyway, null check is really really fast.